# Should the wiki for the [data-protection] tag be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

*Please note that I don't think I can contribute any useful improvement to this, I just wanted to draw some attention to this.*

The wiki for [data-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-protection) currently reads as follow:

Excerpt:

> Tag for questions relating to personal data protection, and legal issues regarding privacy.

Description:

> The Data Protection Act (DPA) is law in most countries with a number of rules and regulations concerning personal and private data.
>
> - Data is processed fairly and lawfully
> - Data shouldn't be given away without permission
> - Data should be relevant and not excessive
> - Data should be accurate and up to date
> - Data should only be kept for as long as necessary
> - Individuals have the right to check data which is about them
> - Data should be securely kept
> - Data must not be transferred to another country without adequate data protection
>
> People involved include the data subject - the person who the data is about and the data controller - the person in charge of handling the data.

With regard to the excerpt - Would Stack Overflow be the most appropriate place to discuss legal issues?

With regard to the description - I don't have any issue with the bullet points, it's more with this statement at the top:

> The Data Protection Act (DPA) is law in most countries with a number of rules and regulations concerning personal and private data.

This is simply so broad that it can't be correct. I'm pretty sure that there are still jurisdictions in this world that don't have data protection laws and if they do surely they don't all share the same denomination nor do they apply in the same way.

**Question:** Do you think the "legal" bits should be removed and repurpose this tag for the technical means available to keep data secure?

Comment: We should probably burn this tag to hell as it is not even that specific and if new people read that excerpt, there will be many off-topic questions arising